# enumerate function in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to iterate over an array of strings, using the global enumerate function in Swift.

It looks like this:

```
let fontNames = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName)

 for (index, value) in enumerate(fontNames) {
    // Do something here     
  }
```

But Xcode complains with an error saying

Cannot convert the expression's type 'EnumerateGenerator' to type '$T1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>`fontNamesForFamilyName()` returns AnyObject[]!, which can't be directly enumerated. You have explicitly type your fontNames array.</s>

```
let fontNames: Array = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName)
for (index, value : AnyObject) in enumerate(fontNames) {
    println(value)
}
```

And as @Van Du Tran pointed out in the comments below, the syntax for enumerate has changed in Swift 2. Now you can use the following.

```
let fontNames: Array = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName)
for (index, value) in fontNames.enumerate() {
    print(value)
}
```

It's also worth noting that since `fontNamesForFamilyName` now uses an Objective C generic type, it returns `[String]` so no conversion from `AnyObject` is needed.

Comment: According to the API docs, that function actually returns `AnyObject[]!`

Comment: Yeah it was my understanding - after reading the docs - that it returned an array of AnyObjects which I assumed could be enumerated. But 0x7ffffff's answer works.

Comment: @0x7fffffff No problem. Color me surprised that can't be enumerated directly. Hm.

Comment: @VanDuTran Thanks for pointing that out. I've added an updated version to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I might disagree with @0x7fffffff's answer. I think the issue is not that `AnyObject[]` can't be directly enumerated, but rather that it's returned as an implicitly unwrapped optional.

As a test:

```
    let myStuff: AnyObject[] = ["Neat"]
    for (index, value) in enumerate(myStuff) { // < No issues
        print("\(value)")
    }

    let myStuff2: AnyObject[]! = ["Neat"]
    for (index, value) in enumerate(myStuff2) { // < Compiler error
        print("\(value)")
    }
```

I think a better solution is to unwrap the optional in your `enumerate()` function:

```
for (index, value) in enumerate(fontNames!) { // < Note the bang
...
```

Comment: I guess what I don't understand though: If it's being returned to us as an implicitly *unwrapped* optional, why do we need to *unwrap* it again to use it? It seems like the unwrapping is happening twice.

Comment: Good question, and/but it looks like they fixed this as of 6 GM.  That said, the cast in "let myStuff = ..." no longer works, but evidently you don't need it anyway. <code>let myStuff2: [String]! = ["Neat"]
for (index, value) in enumerate(myStuff2) { /* now works */
 print("\(value), \(myStuff2[index])")
}
</code>

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a futuristic answer :)

In **Swift 2.0**, the signature of the method is:

```
class func fontNamesForFamilyName(_ familyName: String) -> [String]
```

And to use it:

```
let fontNames = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName)

for (index, value) in fontNames.enumerate() {
    // Do something here     
}
```

In **Swift 1.2**, the signature of the method is:

```
class func fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName: String) -> [AnyObject]
```

And to use it:

```
let fontNames = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName)

for (index, value) in enumerate(fontNames) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Note that in both cases, `fontNames` is *not* an optional.